# PHP regular expression to check if MM/DD are within proper range

Tags: php, regex, date

I have a form that keeps throwing an error to users because they don't understand that their birthdate needs to be in MM/DD format. I'm not asking for the year, but some put it in as MM/YY and don't realize I want the *day* not the year.

I tried to do this with regex but couldn't figure it out, so I wrote this

```
$ckdate = explode("/", $mySub['Birthday']);
if($ckdate[0]>12 || $ckdate[0]<1){
    echo 'Please make sure your birthdate is in a valid format MM/DD, we ask for month and day only'; 
    return;
}
if($ckdate[1]>31 || $ckdate[1]<1){
    echo 'Please make sure your birthdate is in a valid format MM/DD, we ask for month and day only'; 
    return;
}
```

Is this the best way to do this? It seems inefficient. I'm wondering if regex is the way, or is there a PHP function to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your mixing js with php

Comment: [You don't need regex](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) for this, the way you're doing it is probably fine. However, you've created this problem by using a format that users are not expecting. [You're making them think!](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Think-Steve-Krug/dp/3826697057/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1436916080&sr=8-2&keywords=dont+make+me+think)

Comment: There is an overlap between a 2 digit month and a 2 digit year that could be valid as both. How can you tell the difference? It might be better to use a drop box for both month and day.

Comment: Another approach could be redesigning your form to increase usability.   For instance, you could have an input with a placeholder that states "month" and one that states "year."  Never assume a user thinks the way you do.  Catching mistakes is good, but it's probably a better idea to prevent the mistake from happening in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the input all. Thanks for verifying that I don't need regex. I do have a jquery datepicker, but it wasn't working. Once I re-enable that, it should help and that is to nomistic's point of preventing the mistake from happening in the first place. But the answer below with checkdate could also work for the validation. Standby...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`checkdate()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) and just enter a dummy year. For example: `checkdate($m, $d, 2000)`.

Note: you probably want to use a leap year as the dummy year so those born on February 29th aren't left out in the cold.

Comment: Great suggestion. This reduces my code and makes it a little cleaner. Now I only need one if statement.

Comment: Yea, always try to use built-in functionality as it's less error prone, and you don't have to duplicate the functionality.